# Cookies in ASP.NET-Call Back to another page

Tags: asp.net, cookies, authentication, callback, change-password

do you know how cookies works on ASP.NET? could you tell me?
and how to call the cookies to another page?
i have login form, and i use cookies. but i can't call that cookies to another page. i want to use some data from login form (it's like domain name, username and password) to do change password from changepassword.aspx form.
somebody please help me.

```js
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string adPath = "LDAP://mydomain.com"; //Path to your LDAP directory server
  LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
  try
  {
    if(true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated(txtDomain.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
      //string groups = adAuth.GetGroups();
      string groups = txtUsername.Text;
      //Create the ticket, and add the groups.
      bool isCookiePersistent = chkPersist.Checked;
      FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
                txtUsername.Text,DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups);

      //Encrypt the ticket.
      string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

      //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
      HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

      if(true == isCookiePersistent)
      authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

      //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
      Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

      //You can redirect now.
      Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text, false));
    }
    else
    {
      errorLabel.Text = "Authentication did not succeed. Check user name and password.";
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    errorLabel.Text = "Error authenticating. " + ex.Message;
  }
}
</script>
```

this is how use cookies in login form.
how can i use cookies in change password form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the cookie value in asp.net website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490129/how-to-get-the-cookie-value-in-asp-net-website)

Comment: that code connect to sql, but my data in ldap directory.

Comment: Are you getting any exception, If you see the microsoft documentation you also have to modify web.config <identity impersonate="true"/>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/">
   </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
  <identity impersonate="true"/>
  <compilation debug="true"/></system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: I guess you following same link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: yes i used that code, but how can i change password and connect to that code? thanks for answering.