# Access Token From Cookies (Identity Server 6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-4.8, duende-identity-server

In this Project I have identity server(Asp.net core) ,Web application(.net Framework 4.8) and api (Asp.net Core)

api in get access token from cookie in identity server

in this web application i am get access token using this method so get access token from cookie successful

```
var authResult = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("cookies");
var props = authResult.Properties.Dictionary;
props.TryGetValue("access_token", out var accessToken)
```

but this method not working in asp.net core api

this method to not get access token from cookies

there are three same cookie available in web and api

this is a cookie name below hear

.AspNetcookies
idsrv.session
idsrv

api in get access token from cookie

get solution in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Framework 4.8 you can use the [Request.Cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.cookies?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1#System_Web_HttpRequest_Cookies) collection

Example: `var s = Request.Cookies["access_token"].Value;`

identical question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490129/how-to-get-the-cookie-value-in-asp-net-website)

Comment: Api in use Asp .net core

Comment: I am edit question in my project i get only three cookie (.AspNetcookies, .idsrv.session, idsrv)

Comment: Ah so you wanna access the cookies in the api via the http header right? 

What you could try is something like this. `var s = Request.Headers.GetCookies("access_token").FirstOrdDefault()?` 
didnt tested it by myself but it could work out.